# Extracting sub string with regexp

Tags: c#, regex, string, substring, extract

I have the following kind of text inside my source code files:

```
html += T.m('current value of the quality level of the security service (as established from the diagnostic phase).');
or
{header: T.m("Service to Improve"), dataIndex : 'searvicesToImprove', hideable: false},
or
Ext.getCmp('MAX_ACTION_PLANS_PAGE').setText(T.m('od') + ' ' + MAX_ACTION_PLANS_PAGE);
```

I want to extract the substring inside of the brackets, ie. from `T.m(X)` I want to get the `X` without the quote brackets or with them, and I would trim them afterwards.

So in other words I would like something like this:

```
regex( "T.m('X')" | "T.m("X")" );
and then say:
listOfMatches.add(X);
```

I know this is usually done with regexp, but I'm not that good with regexp, haven't used it much, only for basic samples.
Any help is very much appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try {
    Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"T\.m\([""|'](.+?)[""|']\)");
    Match matchResults = regexObj.Match(subjectString);
    while (matchResults.Success) {
        var neededvalue = matchResults.Groups[1].Value;
    } 
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Comment: Empty try catch. Aargh!

Comment: @AppDeveloper Adding a comment doesn't mean it is not empty.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - ahh, i read that statement in wrong way ! sry for that !

Comment: Thanks a million, yours is the only one that doesn't break the format "T.m(stuff)", unlike the others. 
That's why I have marked your answer as the correct one.

Comment: Also I don't mind the empty try-catch block, but that's just me.

Answer (score 2):

```
var regex = new Regex(@"T\.m\((?<MyGroup>.*)\)");
var match =regex.Match(subject);
if(match.Success)
{
    var found =  match.Groups["MyGroup"].Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a regex and want all the parts seperate, this might work

```
 #  @"(?s)T\.m\(((['""])((?:(?!\2).)*)\2)\)"

 (?s)                          # dot all modifier
 T \. m                        # 'T.m'
 \(                            # Open parenth
 (                             # (1 start), Quoted part
      ( ['"] )                      # (2), Open Quote
      (                             # (3 start), Body of quoted part
           (?:                           # grouping
                (?! \2 )                      # lookahead, not a quote
                .                             # any char
           )*                            # end grouping, do 0 or more times
      )                             # (3 end)
      \2                            # Close quote (group (2) backreference)
 )                             # (1 end), Quoted part
 \)                            # Close parenth
```

Just take what you need from the groups